# checkstyle error when analyzing java code

Tags: spring-boot, checkstyle

i got this error when launching checkstyle analysis in a spring boot app :

```
SpringBootBackend.java:7:1  error: Les classes utilitaires ne doivent pas avoir de constructeur par dÃ©faut ou public.
```

Code:

```
  public class SpringBootBackend{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootBackend.class, args);
   }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: My French leaves a lot to be desired, but does the error go away if you declare a public constructor in your class?

Comment: no. In fact, the error tell us that the constructor should not be by default or public.

Comment: The error message in English is `Utility classes should not have a public or default constructor.`. It is from the check `HideUtilityClassConstructor`. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#HideUtilityClassConstructor

Answer (score 1):

While the previous answer is technically correct from the checkstyle perspective, it won't work in this case because Spring Boot will try to create an instance of this class and it will fail because of the `private` constructor.

In this case, I decided to suppress this violation with the annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:hideutilityclassconstructor")
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a configuration file that suppress checks on files, `checkstyle-suppressions.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="SpringBootApplication.java" checks="HideUtilityClassConstructor" />
</suppressions>
```

In `maven-checkstyle-plugin` plugin configuration, add location of `checkstyle-suppressions.xml`

```
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>quality/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <suppressionsLocation>quality/checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes which contain only static methods are considered "utility classes" by this check. Such classes should have only private constructors, so that they are not accidentally instantiated. They should also be `final`.

So, you can add a constructor like this:

```java
private SpringBootBackend() {}
```

and possibly declare the class `final`, and the error should be gone.

Comment: This solution may work for regular Java class but not for Spring Boot Main class